# Strange behavior of assert_redirected_to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
it 'should create' do
  post :create, investor: VALID_CREATE_PARAMS
  expect(response).to redirect_to(controller: 'admin/investors', action: 'show')
end
```

It generates following error:

```
1) Admin::InvestorsController create should create
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to(controller: 'admin/investors', action: 'show')

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/investors"}
```

The routes are

```
namespace :admin do

  resources :investors

end
```

How can I fix this issue? I have no option to assert redirection with `admin_investor_path`, because I keep url params while redirecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show action by default requires an id to be passed as well, without the id it can't generate the url

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it like this:

```
expect(response).to redirect_to(controller: 'admin/investors', action: 'show', id: assigns(:investor).id )
```